# can't write on a string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I have the next function and i want to print some parameters separated by a comma, my problem is that the console didn't show anything when "parametro[i] = linea[i]" in the FOR iteration.
Example:
Parametro 1: []

```
void funcionSeparadora (string linea){

int numParametros = 1;
string parametro;
for (int unsigned i=0;i<linea.length();i++){

    if (linea[i] == ','){
        cout <<"Parámetro "<<numParametros<<": "<<"["<< parametro <<"]"<< '\n';
        numParametros++;
    }
    else (parametro[i] = linea[i]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly the way you handle the filling of parametro was wrong. Fixed version:

```
void funcionSeparadora(string linea) {
    int numParametros = 1;
    string parametro;
    for (int unsigned i = 0; i<linea.length(); i++) {

        if (linea[i] == ',') {
            cout << "Parámetro " << numParametros << ": " << "[" << parametro << "]" << '\n';
            numParametros++;
            parametro.clear();
        }
        else {
            parametro += linea[i];
        }
    }
    if (!parametro.empty()) {
        cout << "Parámetro " << numParametros << ": " << "[" << parametro << "]" << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Points you missed

1. Use curly brackets in else condition
2. Use `size_t` instead of unsigned in in for loop
3. initialize the `parametro` variable with necessary length

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void funcionSeparadora(string linea) {

    int numParametros = 1;
    string parametro(linea.length(),' ');
    for (size_t i = 0; i < linea.length(); i++) {

        if (linea[i] == ',') {
            cout << "Parámetro " << numParametros << ": " << "[" << parametro << "]" << endl;
            numParametros++;
        }
        else { 
            parametro[i] = linea[i];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    funcionSeparadora("what is this,");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```